# How to create split and morph animation together using bezier curves in android

Tags: android, android-animation, uibezierpath, bezier, morphing

[Music widget by JIE LIU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2qKR.gif)

I want to add a similar gooey and morphing effect to my android app.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a gooey animation easily using Canvas animations which is supported by android.